# How to get the device contact using phonegap 2.0.0?

Tags: android, cordova

Am developing a android application using phonegap(Cordova 2.0.0). I need the retrieve the device contacts. I have tried with code given this doc

> http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts

my code as follows

```
$("#shareoptions3").live('click',function(){        

    var options = new ContactFindOptions();

    options.multiple  = true; 
    var fields = ["displayName","phoneNumbers"];//["displayName", "name","phoneNumbers"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onContactSuccess, onContactError, options);
});

function onContactSuccess(contacts) {//alert(contacts.length);

    for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
        // display phone numbers
        for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) {
            alert("Type: " + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].type + "\n" + 
                "Value: "  + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value + "\n" + 
                "Preferred: "  + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].pref);
        }
    }
};

// onError: Failed to get the contacts
//
function onContactError(contactError) {
    console.log('Error in getting contacts!');
}
```

I am getting message in Logcat like this :

> Error in success callback: Contacts3 = TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null at file:///android_asset/www/JS/cordova-2.0.0.js:258

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: Hi! Did you had any contact in your device when you tried your app?

Comment: @ Littm  :  yes , Am getting the total no. contact count ..(in line //alert(contacts.length);
)

Comment: I mean does `alert(contacts.length)` give you `0` ?

Comment: @ Littm 2 : no, am getting alert msg like 29. There are 29 contacts are there in my device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of your contact may not have a telephone number, and that is why you'll get a `null` value instead of a phone number.

So, in your `for` loop, one of the `contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length` wil generate an error.

I suggest you to first check if the `phoneNumbers` is `null` or not, before displaying / alerting it, by using:

```
if(contacts[i].phoneNumbers != null)
```

**In the end, you may try something like this:**

```
$("#shareoptions3").live('click',function(){        

    var options = new ContactFindOptions();

    options.multiple  = true; 
    var fields = ["displayName","phoneNumbers"];//["displayName", "name","phoneNumbers"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onContactSuccess, onContactError, options);
});

function onContactSuccess(contacts) {//alert(contacts.length);

    for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {

        // display phone numbers

        if(contacts[i].phoneNumbers != null)  // Checking if not null
            for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) {
                alert("Type: " + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].type + "\n" + 
                    "Value: "  + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value + "\n" + 
                    "Preferred: "  + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].pref);
            }
    }
};

// onError: Failed to get the contacts
//
function onContactError(contactError) {
    console.log('Error in getting contacts!');
}
```

Hope this helps, let me know if this works for you.